# Javascript button onclick doesn't work

Tags: javascript, onclick, buttonclick

Hi guys below are two fragments from my code:

```
            case 'i_new_call':
        {
            if (oSipSessionCall) {
                // do not accept the incoming call if we're already 'in call'
                e.newSession.hangup(); // comment this line for multi-line support
            }
            else {
                oSipSessionCall = e.newSession;
                oSipSessionCall.setConfiguration(oConfigCall);
                uiBtnReceive('Answer');
                btnCall.disabled = true;
                btnHangUp.disabled = false;

                startRingTone();

                var sRemoteNumber = (oSipSessionCall.getRemoteFriendlyName() || 'unknown');
                txtCallStatus.innerHTML = "<i>Incoming call from [<b>" + sRemoteNumber + "</b>]</i>";
                showNotifICall(sRemoteNumber);
            }
            break;
        }
```

My function is:

```
function uiBtnReceive() {

            var btnAccept = document.getElementsByName("Accept");
            btnAccept.onclick = function () { sipCall(bDisableVideo ? 'call-audio' : 'call-audiovideo'); };
        }
    }
```

Button:

```
<input type="button" name="Accept" style="margin: 0; vertical-align:middle; height: 100%;" class="btn btn-primary" value="Accept"/>
```

The problem is that when I create button with id of btnAccept it works. But when I am trying to use element name it doesn't triggered. Any idea how can I solve this.

Comment: `getElementsByName("Accept")` always returns an array of all the elements with the `name="Accept"` attribute, you could specify to only take the first like this: `getElementsByName("Accept")[0]`

Comment: yes I saw thank you so much for comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getElementsByName` returns `array` of `elements` you will need to use `index` to get the `object` and attach `event`.

```
function uiBtnReceive() {
   var btnAccept = document.getElementsByName('Accept')[0];
   btnAccept.onclick = function () { sipCall(bDisableVideo ? 'call-audio' : 'call-audiovideo'); };

}
```

Comment: oooo man thank you so much ))))))))) I just realised )))))))))))))))))))))))) Thanks again